# Waiting for visa to be express mailed one day before international flight

Tags: visas, airlines, delays, ord

I have an international flight leaving early Tuesday morning. The visa agency has had my passport and application for more than 3 weeks, but due to problems with the photograph and embassy closures they will not be able to get my visa until Monday afternoon. The agency has offered to same-day deliver the visa as soon as they pick it up from the embassy. It's possible that if they can get my passport to FedEx or UPS by 3PM Monday, that it will arrive in the evening by 9PM. But should I call the airline and prepare for the possibility that my visa won't arrive in time? Or is it possible to arrange my visa to be sent to the layover airport (ORD) on Tuesday?

Comment: I called the airline (AA) and they said because it's an award flight (purchased with miles) that I can change the flight for free. But the only available flight at the same award price is a month away. I can change any time before the flight, so I'll wait until monday evening and hope my visa arrives.

Comment: I can find the relevant postage delivery times from FedEx, UPS, and USPS, but there still remains the uncertainty of whether it will processed in time and delivered according to the carrier's guarantee.

Comment: What ended up happening?

Comment: The visa agency was kind enough to same-day deliver the passport at their own expense and it arrived on time the night before my flight. I figured in the worst case I would have to pay a penalty for changing the flight at the last minute.

Comment: Just as a FYI, the airline will not care if your visa did not arrive on time. They would only be concerned about your fare restrictions (ie, cancellation fees, rebooking, etc.). As far as the airline is concerned, as long as it _looks like_ you have a visa, they will accept you for boarding. They need to do this check due to penalties on airlines if they transport passengers that are then rejected entry due to missing/expired documents.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid interesting. I've always wondered what happens when a passenger is rejected entry at the border. Do they have a special counter to buy return tickets within customs?

Comment: No, they are returned back at the cost of the airline that transported them. That's why airlines check your immigration documents; the penalty is applied on the deadline. It happened to me (flight was delayed, and midnight passed and my valid visa became invalid when I walked up to the counter). I was held at the airport, and then transported back on the same airline.

Comment: Wow, that's tough on the airlines because there could be so many cases where it would be impossible for the airline to determine a passenger would be rejected at the border.

Comment: @pnuts Saudi Arabia

Comment: @ReedG.Law That's the point. In many places there are fines *for the airline* as well on top of that to give them even stronger incentives to check passengers' documents carefully and essentially outsource border checks so that unwanted people don't even make it to the country's territory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you, not the airline, to have a valid visa for any countries you may be visiting.

You've not clarified which countries the missing visa is for, but a responsibility the airline DOES have is to ensure you have completed the required visa acquisition for any countries that they fly you to.  As a result, if your missing visa is one of these, they're unlikely to want to risk flying you to said countries, even if you promise you'll get the visa at the layover airport (Chicago ORD).

It's generally pretty risky going to any country without a visa/onwards visa - and the US especially don't take kindly to even forgetting to fill out an ESTA for those who don't require visas :/

You COULD call the airline and see if they'll change your flight to give you more time to obtain said visa, but other than that, the airline is out of the equation here - it's between you and the visa company to get it sorted beforehand.

(I realise you've already had this flight and the visa did manage to arrive in time, but I wanted to clarify for future readers.)